# Calc in calc not working in safari

Tags: css, safari, sass

I'm using SCSS & some calc fonction to do a very good responsive design for my website.

I have this calc in my file :

```
height: calc(#{75vh} - #{$header-height});
```

In chrome is working perfectly, my image take the correct size, but in safari the generated css do no work.

Here the generated css :

```
height: calc(75vh - calc(110px));
```

If you have an idea...

Comment: Remove the calc from 'calc(110px)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nested `calc()` is unnecessary. Works fine if you remove that.

```
height: calc(75vh - 110px);
```

```css
html,body {
  height: 100vh;
}
div {
  background: red;
  height: calc(75vh - 110px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: my $header-height cames from a calc of two other height. I no i can simplify it change the var to the result of my first calc. But why it's work on chrome and not safari, they are both using webkit

Comment: @OrcusZ I don't know why safari doesn't recognize it as a valid value, but it's invalid per the dev tools. Chrome uses blink, which is a fork of webkit, so they aren't the same.

Comment: Ok, so i will change to my css. Thanks for the explanations